# what is the masterpage on this asp.net webformpage?

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net webformpage without a MasterPageFile property at the top but I have asp:content tags in there. I assume this page has a masterpage what is the masterpage in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `web.config` maybe there is a global master page define in the `<page>` element there.

Also, check the code-behind. Maybe it's declared in code.